# C# Control menu position across multiple monitors

Tags: c#, menu, multiple-monitors

I have two monitors. I am seeing some strange behaviour when I access the MenuStrip of my C# application near the edge of my left monitor.

Case 1: In this screenshot I have opened SubMenu1 when the window is fairly close to the edge of my left monitor. SubMenu2 shows up on the leftmost edge of my right monitor.

[image: Gap]

Case 2: I then move my application a few pixels to the left and now SubMenu2 appears to the left of SubMenu1.

[image: No Gap]

In my opinion, Case 2 looks much nicer. Is there any way to force C# to always show the menu like in Case 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control it in your program, set the SubMenu1's RightToLeft property to RightToLeft.Yes.  That has some side effects, the text will now be right-aligned and the arrow will point the correct way.  You'd probably want to set the property in the a DropDownOpening event handler for the "Menu" item.

Comment: But wouldn't you now have the exact same problem if the form was in the right window, close to the left edge?

Comment: @rmx - note the mention of the DropDownOpening event.

Answer (score 2):

Short of writing your own `MenuStrip` component, there is no way to specify which side the `MenuItem` should open on.

Besides, unless this is a specific requirement of the software (which I highly doubt), I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: I don't want to specify a particular side to always be used. However, there is clearly some heuristic being used to place the submenu and I want to force that to avoid leaving a gap when placing the submenu.